# pear validate.php - No such file or directory

Tags: php

I have a website that uses pear's validate.php.

I use ubuntu on my development environment and I did install php-pear.

But when I open the page that has a require_once('Validate.php'), I get the error message:

Warning: require_once(Validate.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

What am I missing?

thanks

Nico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEAR's [Validate](http://pear.php.net/package/Validate) class is not bundled with the default distribution.  You must [install it](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.installing.php) separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried installing it but I get teh error:

0 down vote favorite
share [fb] share [tw]
 

Hi.

When trying to install pear packages I get the following error:

sudo pear install validate

PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR::raiseErro() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 165

This: PEAR::raiseErro() seems to be the problem.

How do I even fix this?!

Comment: There seems to be a missing `r` there.  That's ... odd.  A bit of poking in Google suggests that [it's a bug in recent versions of the Debian `php-pear` package](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=619307) -- they pulled a copy from the PEAR folks at an inopportune time.  It's been fixed upstream, and the last message in the bug suggests that updated packages have been made available.

Comment: I use ubuntu. My big question now is: How do I get this working with ubuntu. I use ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Debian.  You will need to either install PEAR manually (removing the `php-pear` package), or wait for Ubuntu to update their package from Debian.  It might be available in the "testing" repo.

Comment: I'll try patience for a few days. After that I'll make my hands dirty.
Thanks.